# How would I search through all nested children of a custom class?

Tags: c#

I have a table in a database which looks like this:

```
|    id    | parentID |    name     |
|----------+----------+-------------|
|ABCD-12345|          |    Top      |
|----------+----------+-------------|
|ABCD-23456|ABCD-12345|   Middle    |
|----------+----------+-------------|
|ABCD-34567|ABCD-23456|   Bottom    |
|----------+----------+-------------|
|ABCD-45678|ABCD-23456|   Bottom    |
```

etc. - Basically, a hierarchical structure of N depth. I've taken this and shoved it into a datatable.

I have the following class built to hold this data:

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string parentID { get; set; }
    public List<TreeNode> children { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to go through each of these DataTable rows and insert them into the appropriate location in the TreeNode structure, but I'm super confused as to how I should approach this.

The main point of confusion for me is how I search through the **entire existing structure** of TreeNodes to see if a node with the parentID exists. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work:

```
public List<TreeNode> BuildTree(int currNode, List<TreeNode> treeList, DataTable dt)
{
    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        if(row[1].ToString() == treeList[currNode].id)
        {
            treeList[currNode].children.Add(new TreeNode
            {
                id = row[0].ToString(),
                name = row[2].ToString(),
                parentID = row[1].ToString()
            });
            dt.Rows.Remove(row);

            if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                currNode++;
                BuildTree(currNode, treeList, dt);
            }
            else
            {
                return treeList;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem is this line:

```
if(row[1].ToString() == treeList[currNode].id)
```

which gets an out of range exception, because I have a root at index 0, so on the second run (when `currNode` is 1), it breaks. I need to traverse to `treeList[0].Children[int]`, followed by `treeList[0].Children[int].Children[int]` and so on and so forth.

So how do I accomplish this goal?

Comment: Wouldn't your `treeList` always contain only the parent (hence a list with length 1 at all times)? Or am I incorrect?

Comment: I mean, that's what the code does right now, but that's what I'm trying to fix with this post. I'm not entirely sure I understand your question.

Comment: The question is, given that your `DataTable` has four items, do you want the `BuildTree()` to return a list with four `TreeNode` elements with parent-child relations set right, or do you want it to return just the root `TreeNode` object, and each of it's children will containing other elements defining the tree?

Comment: Oh, I see - the latter of the two is my goal. So using the example `DataTable`, my root `TreeNode` would have an ID of ABCD-12345. It would have a list of a single child `TreeNode` object which has an ID of ABCD-23456. That `TreeNode`, in turn, would have a list of two child `TreeNode` objects with the IDs ABCD-34567 and ABCD-45678. The issue is that I don't know how deep these will nest ahead of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'm going to modify the `TreeNode` class for our convenience. It's not necessary, but just a nice to have. Also I'm going to assume that in your datatable you've done your error checking and there's only one node with `ParentId = ""`.

```
public class TreeNode
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ParentID { get; set; }
    public List<TreeNode> Children { get; set; }

    public TreeNode()
    {
        Id = Name = ParentID = string.Empty;
        Children = new List<TreeNode>();
    }

    public bool IsRoot { get { return ParentID == string.Empty; } }
    public bool IsChild { get { return Children == null || Children.Count == 0; } }
}
```

First, I'd convert your datatable data into a list of `TreeNode` objects. Forget about relationships, just create a list with each objects `Children` being empty. I wrote a method to simulate data retrival from datatable. Instead of that you can use your actual datatable.

```
static List<DataTableData> GetDataTableData()
{
    var data = new List<DataTableData>
    {
        new DataTableData() { Id = "23456", ParentID = "12345", Name = "Middle" },
        new DataTableData() { Id = "55555", ParentID = "12345", Name = "Middle" },
        new DataTableData() { Id = "34567", ParentID = "23456", Name = "Bottom" },
        new DataTableData() { Id = "12345", ParentID = string.Empty, Name = "Top" },
        new DataTableData() { Id = "45678", ParentID = "23456", Name = "Bottom" },
        new DataTableData() { Id = "66666", ParentID = "55555", Name = "Bottom" }
    };
    return data;
}
```

And this is what your `Main()` would look like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var treeNodes = new List<TreeNode>();

    var dataTable = GetDataTableData();
    foreach (var data in dataTable)
    {
        treeNodes.Add(new TreeNode() { Id = data.Id, Name = data.Name, ParentID = data.ParentID });
    }

    var root = BuildTree(treeNodes);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now, in my `BuildTree()` method, instead of passing the datatable I can pass my `TreeNode` list, and return just the root node.

```
public static TreeNode BuildTree(List<TreeNode> nodes)
{
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        node.Children = nodes.Where(x => x.ParentID == node.Id).ToList();
    }

    return nodes.Find(x => x.IsRoot);
}
```

---

### `BuildTree()` Breakdown

The `nodes` list already have all the nodes corresponding to data in your datatable. The `BuildTree()` is merely going to create the parent-child relations and fill in each object's `Children` list.

So I iterate through the list, and see what other elements in the list are supposed to be its children. When you have iterated through the list you'd created all the parent-child relationships. Finally, I pick the root node (the one who's `ParentId` is empty) and return it.

---

### Edit

Here's an easy method to print and verify your tree.

```
static void PrintTree(TreeNode node, int indents)
{
    for (int tab = 0; tab < indents; tab++)
    {
        Console.Write("\t");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", node.Id, node.Name);
    if (node.Children != null && node.Children.Count > 0)
    {
        indents++;
        foreach (var child in node.Children)
        {
            PrintTree(child, indents);
        }
    }
}
```

My output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Guidelines be damned, this was a great answer and it really helped with something that was driving me insane. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a class structure then you need a class with a recursive method.  Not sure how efficient this will be if it gets too big.  Execute the method from the top of the tree.

```
public class TreeNode  
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string parentID { get; set; }
    public List<TreeNode> children { get; set; }

    public TreeNode() {
        children = new List<TreeNode>();
    }

    public TreeNode FindParentWithID(string ID)
    {
        TreeNode ParentWithID = null;

        //check my parentID if i am the one being looked for then return
        if (id == ID) return this;

        //search children
        foreach (TreeNode treeNode in children)
        {
            ParentWithID = treeNode.FindParentWithID(ID);

            if (ParentWithID != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return ParentWithID;
    }
}
```

You would load your data into the classes from the database. I had to hard code the values for the example to work:

TreeNode treeNode5 = new TreeNode() { id = "ABCD-12345", parentID = null, name = "Top" };

```
        TreeNode treeNode6 = new TreeNode() { id = "ABCD-12346", parentID = "ABCD-12345", name = "Middle" };
        treeNode5.children.Add(treeNode6);

        TreeNode treeNode7 = new TreeNode() { id = "ABCD-12347", parentID = "ABCD-12346", name = "Bottom" };
        TreeNode treeNode8 = new TreeNode() { id = "ABCD-12348", parentID = "ABCD-12346", name = "Bottom" };
        treeNode6.children.Add(treeNode7);
        treeNode6.children.Add(treeNode8);

        TreeNode topOne = treeNode5.FindParentWithID("ABCD-12346");
```

topOne will be end up being treeNode6 name="Middle" in this example.

Answer (score 0):

try this code, i have same issue and it works perfectly

this method used to build tree from list of items, by looping through all items, and add each item to its parent's child list. and return only the root item with its nested child.

```
public TreeNode BuildTree(List<TreeNode> source)
{
    // build the children list for each item
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        var itm = source.Where(i => i.parentID == item.Id).ToList();
        item.ChildItems = itm;
    }
    // return only the root parents with its child inside
    return source.Where(i => i.parentID == null).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

noting that this method return only on TreeNode Object with its child, you can return List by changing **`.FirstOrDefault()`** to **`.ToList(`)** in return line